# How to make nautilus forget an invalid ssh connection whose credentials were stored for forever?

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, gnome-shell, nautilus

I wanted to access some files on a remote. I used nautilus, entered `ssh://my-ssh-server` location  bar, entered my user and password information and made it store the credentials for forever.

Now I must have mistyped my password as I get an error: `Too many authentication failures`.  Though there doesn't appear an obvious way to change my credentials with which it should try to connect to the ssh connection.

(I can still connect to my openssh server via terminal, but for convenience I like to access it through nautilus.)

[image: Too many authentication failures popup by nautilus]

How to make nautilus forget the password for the ssh connection?

Answer (score 2):

Credentials for servers accessed via GVFS are stored in GNOME Keyring through *libsecret*. Use the graphical Seahorse app or `secret-tool` to delete them.

1. `secret-tool search --all xdg:schema org.gnome.keyring.NetworkPassword`
2. `secret-tool clear protocol "ssh" server "example.com" ...`

Answer (score 0):

I circumvented the credentials by using my public key to allow myself to login remotely on my ssh server:

I registered my key like so:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@my-ssh-server "cat - >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

That way nautilus uses that as a default instead of the credentials.

---

Nautilus may have exceeded the amount of allowed logins. You may have to restart the ssh-server / unban your ip on the ssh-server before you are able to etablish a new connection to your ssh-server.